# PHP Extension not working in LINUX

Tags: php, c, linux

I have created one simple PHP Extension using the following link:

[Sample Hello World PHP extension on Ubuntu](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/)

I have created a PHP Extension successfully as `hello.so`.
I have used `XAMPP` package, in this I have moved this `hello.so` to `/opt/lampp/modules/` 
and I have included the line:

```
extension=hello.so in /opt/lampp/etc/**php.ini**
```

Eventhough, If I called the function from command prompt like:

```
$ php -r ‘hello_world();’
```

even I am getting the error as Function undefined.

Comment: have you restart your Apache service after extension inclusion

Comment: What is the output of php -m, It shows all your loaded modules. Can you see your "hello" in the list ?

Comment: @Swapnil Patil, I think there is No need to restart the apache if he is going to run the script through command line.

Comment: @VineeshPoduval I think we need to restart apache service but main problem is here whether extension is loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

First test your php.ini file whether the extension include successfully or not.For checking call phpinfo() function.

If it is there then

```
php -r 'echo hello_world();'
```

run this on command prompt.I think your missing echo while firing command.You have use echo because it return something.

Note: restart your apache service after extension inclusion.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

To build the `PHP` extension, after creating a `C` file in Linux`, you have to run the following commands:

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure --enable-hello
$ make
```

And do not forget to run:

```
$ sudo make install
```

If you run this command, by default your newly created extension module (`.so`) will be moved to the default dynamic extension path (the path will be displayed after running that command)

Then mention this dynamic extension path in the `PHP.INI` file in the `dynamic_extension directory` section and include your `.so` file  in the `Dynamic Extension` section.
Then restart the `Apache` server and definitely this will work fine.